# Coloring cells based on numbers in string

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

In my sheet, on column A I have a string of numbers divided by commas. Then there are 12 numbered columns, each with its own hour. How can I shade the cells if their column's number is listed in column A?

Here is an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBM5J.png) of what I am hoping to achieve.

```
  | A     | B        | C        | D        | E
1 |       | 1        | 2        | 3        | 4
2 | 1,2,4 | (shaded) | (shaded) |          | (shaded) 
3 | 2,3   |          | (shaded) | (shaded) |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select the whole range
2. Apply conditional fofmatting
3. select custom formula: `=MATCH(B$1,SPLIT($A2,","),0)>0`

[image]

Comment: wow, thanks so much :D. I never knew this was possible with conditional formatting.

Comment: Ok, glad to help :) Please tick the answer as correct